# How can i get the nth row field into image in SSRS 2008r2 - Report Builder 3

Tags: sql-server, image, reporting-services, reporting

I have a report which is just one page per record. The record is chosen using a parameter.

On this report I have space for 4 images, I have a dataset called "AdditionalPhotos". I would like to put the image from the first four rows of this dataset into each of the spaces on the report.

To do this, I planned on using an expression with a function like : First(Image), Second(Image), Third(Image), Fourth(Image). I now realise that SSRS only supports First() and Last() so using some advice from another forum post : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/20493945-578a-4d83-ae3b-e603a3473ac6/nth-row-element-in-a-dataset-ssrs

I have implemented another dataset which contains the same query as the "AdditionalPhotos" but with only 2 columns "ID" and "RowNum". Using this expression I can see a Photo Source field in a textbox, which is great, so the syntax is working.

```
=Lookup(1,Fields!Row.Value,Fields!Source.Value, "AdditionalPhotos")
```

In the value field for the image I have :

```
=Lookup(1,Fields!Row.Value,Fields!Image.Value, "AdditionalPhotos")
```

This doesn't work, I just get a red x icon in the image box of the report. I have the correct MIME type setting and have confirmed this by changing the expression for the image box to :

```
=Fields!Image.Value
```

Any advice or suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to generate row numbers based on an order and/or a partition so that you can select which image you want where.

Something like:

```
SELECT Image,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS rownum
FROM imageTable
```

See:

[MSDN - ROW_NUMBER (TSQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

[MSDN - OVER Clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)